# Promise not resolving before IF STATEMENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, request-promise

I'm trying to check the results of "checkWorkflow" but it seems to be running the "If" statement before checking, i think this because of my console output.
I feel like i'm doing something wrong with the promise, but i'm kinda at a lost at this point.

**Console Output**

Promise { pending } *When i console.log(doesWorkflowExists)

workflow already exists, please rename

error2

```
  const createWorkflow = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    
    const doesWorkflowExists = checkWorkflow(req.name);
    
    if (!doesWorkflowExists) {
      
    console.log('do stuff')
    }
    else {

      console.log('workflow already exists, please rename')
      
  }

  } catch (error) {
    handleError(res, error);
    console.log("error on create workflow");
  }
};
```

**vvvv checkWorkflow vvvv**

```
const checkWorkflow = (name = '') => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Workflow.findOne(
      {
        name,
      },
      (err, item) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error1')
          return reject(buildErrObject(422, err.message));
          
        }

        if (item) {
          console.log('error2')
          
          return reject(buildErrObject(404, "WORKFLOW_ALREADY_EXISTS"));
         
        }

        resolve();
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: So it's working exactly the way it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `checkWorkflow` function, you return a Promise. When you call `checkWorkflow` function like this :

```
const doesWorkflowExists = checkWorkflow(req.name);
```

`doesWorkflowExists` is a pending Promise. On the console, you can see that.

You need to "wait" until the Promise `resolve` the result or `reject` the error. Just add "await" keyword before the function call, like this:

```
const doesWorkflowExists = await checkWorkflow(req.name);
```

The rest seems to be fine, it should work :)